# Distance of convex combination of pairs of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis

Given 4 points $w,x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}^n$ define for $t\in [0,1]$ $f(t)=d(wt + (1-t)x, yt + (1-t)z)$. Is this function convex?
I have found a proof by differentiating twice and calculating a lot but it's not very "nice". Does somebody know any more proofs? Maybe using some geometry or clever argument (but still rigorous)?

Comment: please define $d$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
\begin{align*}
f(t) &= \|tw+(1-t)x-ty-(1-t)z\| \\
&= \|(x-z)+t(w-y-x+z)\| \\
&= \|u+tv\|
\end{align*}
where I've written $u=x-z$ and $v=w-y-x+z$ for simplicity.  The convexity of this function comes directly from the triangle inequality:
\begin{align*}
\|u+((1-\lambda)t_1+\lambda t_2)v\|
&= \|(1-\lambda)(u+t_1 v)+\lambda (u+t_2 v)\| \\
&\le (1-\lambda)\|u+t_1 v\| + \lambda\|u+t_2 v\|
\end{align*}
(One nice thing about this proof is that it works for any norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$, not just the usual Euclidean one.)

Comment: Thanks, I've found this out in the meantime but your way of writing it down is definitely the most elegant I've seen so far.